# Get all data, but show pending data first then Approved data and rejected data

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am writing a sql query in Laravel to fetch all the data for current year but condition is I want to get status -  Pending data first and Approved and Rejected data. According to 'status' = Pending/Approve and Reject?

```
$leaves = Leave::whereRaw('YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(end_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())')
                 ->where('created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId())->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "**orderBy()**" before the "**get()**" method of the query.

**Like this:**

```
$leaves = Leave::whereRaw('YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(end_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())')
->where('created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId())
->orderBy('approved', 'desc')
->get();
```

**Note:** Assuming *approved* as a column in your table where it has boolean value (0 or 1).

Comment: Column name is status which has string values Approve, Pending and Reject. I want to fetch Pending values first and then other Approve and Reject data. Using your query din't worked.

Comment: Great! Then you just have to replace the approved column with status and order desc with asc.

Comment: already tried orderBy query not getting result. Data is coming in a mix pattern of pen, app and rej.                                                                                                                      `  $leaves = Leave::whereRaw('YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(end_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())')
                 ->where('created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId())->orderBy('status','desc')->get(); `

Comment: Assuming that the status column holds more than the approved or rejected string, try adding it to your where clause so that you only get selected data.
Like this :
$leaves = Leave::whereRaw('YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(end_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())')
->where('created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId())
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'approved')
          ->orWhere('status', 'rejected');
})
->orderBy('status','desc')
->get()

Comment: Still Mix data.

Comment: Please explain the data that you have and the data you are returning from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case` in order by query.
Please change your query to

```
$leaves = Leave::whereRaw('YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(end_date)=YEAR(CURDATE())') 
->where('created_by', '=', \Auth::user()->creatorId())
->orderByRaw('case when `status` LIKE "%Pending%" then 1 when `status` LIKE "%Rejected%" then 2 when `status` LIKE "%Approved%" then 3 else 4 end')
->get();
```

Comment: Approve data in not coming in end,  approve data is coming in middle anywhere. All Approve data should be in end before Reject.

Comment: Approved coming middle because We set 2nd priority to 'Approved'. Please change orderByRaw() to `->orderByRaw('case when `status` LIKE "%Pending%" then 1 when `status` LIKE "%Rejected%" then 2 when `status` LIKE "%Approved%" then 3 else 4 end') `

Comment: @AnujTodankar Answer updated. please check